# How to provide version for provided transitive dependencies in sbt?

Tags: playframework, sbt, jira, jira-rest-api, jira-rest-java-api

`[error] (*:update) sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: com.atlassian.sal#sal-api;${sal.version}: not found`

`[error] unresolved dependency: com.atlassian.event#atlassian-event;${event.version}: not found`

**Any way to provide version for provided transitive dependencies ?**

Its easily reproducible in any playframework app when you try to add the https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.atlassian.jira/jira-rest-java-client-core?repo=atlassian-public dependency and compile the project.

https://github.com/sanjeevpande/play-jira-client
The repo with a sample play app. "play compile" will result the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to fix it by adding notTransitive() attribute in the build.sbt

`"com.atlassian.jira" % "jira-rest-java-client-core" % "5.1.0" notTransitive(),`

and by adding the transitive dependencies manually.